# Got singular iterator error in looping with iterator and pop_back

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, reverse-iterator

Giving the below code (say it's named `deque.cpp`)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
  std::deque<int> d = {1, 2, 3};
  for (auto it = d.rbegin(); it != d.rend();) {
    printf("it: %d\n", *it);
    ++it;
    d.pop_back();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -o deque deque.cpp`, it runs well:

```
$ ./deque
it: 3
it: 2
it: 1
```

But if compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (`g++ -std=c++11 -o deque_debug deque.cpp -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, it gets below error:

```
$ ./deque_debug
it: 3
/usr/include/c++/4.8/debug/safe_iterator.h:171:error: attempt to copy-
    construct an iterator from a singular iterator.
...
```

It looks like the second loop's `++it` is constructing from an singular iterator.
But I think after the first loop's `++it`, the iterator points to 2, and `pop_back()` should not invalidate it. Then why the error occurs?

Note: I know the code could be re-write as below:

```
  while (!d.empty()) {
    auto it = d.rbegin();
    printf("it: %d\n", *it);
    d.pop_back();
  }
```

And the error will be gone.

But I do want to know what exactly happens on the error code. (Does it mean the reverse iterator dose not actually point to the node I expect, but the one after it?)

---

**Update:** @Barry's answer resolved the question.
Please let me put an extra related question: the code

```
  for (auto it = d.rbegin(); it != d.rend();) {
    printf("it: %d\n", *it);
    d.pop_back();
    ++it;   // <== moved below pop_back()
  }
```

is expected to be wrong, where `++it` should be operating on an invalidated iterator. But why the code does not cause error?

Comment: *Does it mean the reverse iterator dose not actually point to the node I expect, but the one after it?*  Yes!

Comment: If anybody came here wondering "what's that `singular iterator` anyway, and why should I be afraid of referencing it": I was referred on IRC with [this link](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#iterator.requirements.general-7). C++ standard seems to be referring to "singular" values as invalid ones. The "singular iterator" simply means it points to *la-la land*, for whatever reason *(whether it was uninitialized to begin with, or was invalidated by `erase()` operation)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here arises from what reverse iterators actually are. The relevant relationship for a [reverse iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) is:

> For a reverse iterator `r` constructed from an iterator `i`, the relationship `&*r` == `&*(i-1)` is always true (as long as r is dereferenceable); thus a reverse iterator constructed from a one-past-the-end iterator dereferences to the last element in a sequence.

When we then do [`std::deque::pop_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_back), we invalidate:

> Iterators and references to the erased element are invalidated. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

`rbegin()` is constructed from `end()`. After we increment `it` the first time, `it` will dereference to the `2` but its underlying base iterator is pointing to the `3` - that's the erased element. So the iterators referring to it include your now-advanced reverse iterator. That's why it's invalidated and that's why you're seeing the error that you're seeing.

Reverse iterators are complicated.

---

Instead of incrementing `it`, you could reassign it to `rbegin()`:

```
for (auto it = d.rbegin(); it != d.rend();) {
    printf("it: %d\n", *it);
    d.pop_back();
    // 'it' and 'it+1' are both invalidated
    it = d.rbegin();
}
```

Comment: I do not see a reason why an iterator to the erased element could not still be valid as a one-past-the-end iterator. Isn't the library or standard being excessively conservative here?

Comment: @filipos "I do not see a reason" is generally not a sound argument.

Comment: It is certainly not an argument against your answer. But from a library design point of view, you would not like to invalidate iterators unnecessarily, so as to not limit usage. It is thus a natural question. If you consider for instance a vector (to which the same situation applies) with iterators implemented as pointers, then the pointer to the last element becomes a valid one-past-the-end pointer after removal.

Comment: Good to know that `reverse_iterator` is implemented based on `iterator`, actually the [document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/) does say this but I did not know. _A copy of the original iterator (the base iterator) is kept internally and used to reflect the operations performed on the reverse_iterator: whenever the reverse_iterator is incremented, its base iterator is decreased, and vice versa._

Comment: But why `for (auto it = d.rbegin(); it != d.rend();++it) { d.pop_back();}` avoid the error? After `d.pop_back()`, why `++it` does not trigger the error?

Comment: @Mine The library may fail to diagnose all iterator invalidation errors - but it's still an error. `pop_back()` invalidates past-the-end, which `it` would be pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

Erasing from the underlying container invalidates an iterator. Quoting from the rules:

> Iterators are not dereferenceable if
>
> - they are past-the-end iterators
>   (including pointers past the end of an array) or before-begin
>   iterators. Such iterators may be dereferenceable in a particular
>   implementation, but the library never assumes that they are.
> - they are singular iterators, that is, iterators that are not associated with any sequence. A null pointer, as well as a default-constructed pointer
>   (holding an indeterminate value) is singular
> - they were invalidated by
>   one of the iterator-invalidating operations on the sequence to which
>   they refer.

Your code causes the iterator to be invalidated by the `pop_back` operation, and thus as per the third point above, it becomes non dereferenceable.

In your `while` loop you're avoiding this problem by getting a (new) valid iterator in each loop repetition.

Comment: Specifically the problem is he's increment the iterator *before* `pop_back()` rather than *after*.

Comment: Which iterator is allegedly getting invalidated? `++it` happens before `pop_back()`

Comment: Then why `for (auto it = d.rbegin(); it != d.rend();++it)` avoid the error as well?

Comment: @sleeptightpupper - the iterator is invalidated on the loop iteration *after* the 'pop_back'

Comment: @Barry - same comment to you as above. Please reconsider down votes

Comment: The interesting part of the question is *why* the iterator is getting invalidated by `pop_back`. You're just stating that it is. And dereferencability isn't the problem, the assert is thrown in the comparison with `rend()`.