# How would I refactor a method to erase an element based on a reverse iterator to avoid triggering a warning about copying a singular iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, libstdc++

I have a method that takes a stl reverse iterator, does some work, erases the element, and returns an iterator pointing to the next element.  For example:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> int_vector;
using ReverseIteratorType = decltype(int_vector)::reverse_iterator;

void do_stuff();

ReverseIteratorType erase_with_reverse_iter(ReverseIteratorType iter)
{
    do_stuff();
    std::advance(iter, 1);
    int_vector.erase(iter.base());
    return iter;
}
```

This compiles without warnings and appears to work correctly.  The problem is that when running this code with libstdc++ that verifies every iterator is valid when it is used, an exception is thrown if `iter` points to the last element of a collection because the iterator is treated as a singular iterator after erase, and calling the copy constructor of a singular iterator is disallowed. [(There is a deeper explanation of the issue from another post here.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280744/got-singular-iterator-error-in-looping-with-iterator-and-pop-back).

[godbolt example demonstrating the issue here](https://godbolt.org/z/Pr3cEzc5h)

Two questions

1. Is the disallowing of the copying of a singular iterator a violation of the standard, or is this a sanity check by libstdc++?
2. How would you refactor this to avoid the issue?

Comment: Without further analysis: Don't you think the approach is a bit aggressive? To me it seems you are shuffling data hysterically while "doing stuff". Perhaps I'm reading the pseudo code wrong, but it smells like CPU burn to me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The method conceptually is basically just `std::vector<int>::erase` with all the reverse iterator noise plus an extra step.  I am trusting whoever is calling it not to misuse it.

Comment: Yes, exactly - but the pseudo code afflicts damage to the very container it is looping in. Or did I understand your loop incorrectly?

Comment: @TedLyngmo There is no loop here.

Comment: Ok, then I (read `erase_with_reverse_iter` wrong and) need a [mre]. - Put up an example where you expect one behaviour and get another.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've added a main method in a godbolt to turn it into a running example.

Comment: The erase invalidates `iter`, and then the code returns the invalid `iter`.  Just have the routine return nothing, `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not ignore the return value of `erase()`.

`erase()` invalidates iterators (and pointers and references) to elements at and after the erased element (in container order, not iterator order.  That includes the iterator passed in as a parameter.

You *can* use the iterator returned from `erase()`, but it isn't a reverse iterator.  So you have to convert it back again.